# What is _S_empty_rep_storage used for in this code?

Tags: disassembly

While reversing a C++ program compiled with g++, I've seen a _ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE being used. Running it through c++filt shows that before mangling it's a:

```
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage
```

But what is this _S_empty_rep_storage used for? I included an assembly snippet below where it's used:

```
mov     rax, cs:_ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE_ptr
...
add     rax, 18h
...
mov     [rsp+328h+var_308], rax
mov     [rsp+328h+var_2F8], rax
mov     [rsp+328h+var_2E8], rax
...
lea     r14, [rsp+328h+var_308]
lea     rsi, [rsp+328h+var_2D8] ; std::string *
mov     rdi, r14        ; this
call    __ZNSs4swapERSs ; std::string::swap(std::string &)
lea     rdi, [rsp+328h+var_2D8] ; this
lea     r13, [rsp+328h+var_2F8]
lea     r12, [rsp+328h+var_2E8]
call    __ZNSsD1Ev      ; std::string::~string()
```

So my question is: What's the purpose of _S_empty_rep_storage here? Also why are var_308, var_2f8 and var_2e8 lea'd into r12-14? These registers are not used later on.

Comment: It looks like your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273040/why-is-stdstrings-empty-rep-the-way-it-is

Comment: @JasonGeffner I already read that question, but if it answers my question then I cannot see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the comments at the beginning of libstdc++'s [`basic_string.h`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/libstdc++/api/a01053_source.html) to see how GCC's `std::string` works.Basically, `_S_empty_rep_storage` is a pre-initialized (in fact, zeroed out) representation of an empty string, used to initialize the string in a default constructor. So `var_308`, `var_2F8` and `var_2E8` are three std::string objects, initialized to an empty string.

As for r12-r14, they seem to be used as temporary variables. We can at leas see that `r14` is used to initialize `rdi` - the `this` pointer for the `std::string::swap()` call, so presumably `r12` and `r13` are also used later.